# thread.start_new_thread vs threading.Thread.start

Tags: python, multithreading, new-operator

What is the difference between `thread.start_new_thread` and `threading.Thread.start` in python?
 I have noticed that when `start_new_thread` is called, the new thread terminates as soon as the calling thread terminates. `threading.Thread.start` is the opposite: the calling thread waits for other threads to terminate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `thread` module is the low-level threading API of Python. Its direct usage isn't recommended, unless you really need to. The `threading` module is a high-level API, built on top of `thread`. The `Thread.start` method is actually implemented using `thread.start_new_thread`.

The `daemon` attribute of `Thread` must be set before calling `start`, specifying whether the thread should be a daemon. The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left. By default, `daemon` is `False`, so the thread is not a daemon, and hence the process will wait for all its non-daemon thread to exit, which is the behavior you're observing.

---

P.S. `start_new_thread` really is very low-level. It's just a thin wrapper around the Python core thread launcher, which itself calls the OS thread spawning function.

Answer (score 1):

See the [threading.Thread.daemon](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) flag - basically whenever no non-daemon threads are running, the interpreter terminates.